# Angular: Passing parameter from Controller to Factory

Tags: angularjs

Sorry if duplicate, but really couldn't find the answer at similar issues here at StackOverflow.

Here's the code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IsdYMgcIznQ667ols67b?p=preview

What I want is in `line 19`, I want the program to alert the number I pass, while currently it alerts me a function. The number should be either `0`, `1`, or `2`, depending on which one entry removed `(Remove Student)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory method accepts two parameters, `index` and `callback`.  In that order.

When calling it, you're only passing it a function. This function accepts `index` and `callback`.

Instead, you need to pass it an `index` and a `callback` which accepts `data`.

```
      $scope.removeStudent = function(index) {
          console.log(index);
          studentFactory.removeStudent(index, function(data){ // this is what's different
              console.log(data);
          });
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [return statements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

> Instead of:
>
> ```
>  myAppModule.factory('studentFactory', function (){
>       var students = [
>           {name: 'Mike', age: 34},
>           {name: 'John', age: 24},
>           {name: 'Trey', age: 24}];
>       var factory = {};
>       factory.getStudents = function (callback){
>           callback(students);
>       }
>       factory.removeStudent = function(index, callback) {
>           alert(index);
>           callback(students);
>       }
>       return factory;
>   });
> ```

DO:

```
  myAppModule.factory('studentFactory', function (){
      var students = [
          {name: 'Mike', age: 34},
          {name: 'John', age: 24},
          {name: 'Trey', age: 24}];
      var factory = {};
      factory.getStudents = function (){
          //callback(students);
          return students; 
      }
      factory.removeStudent = function(index) {
          students.splice(index, 1);
          return students;
      }
      return factory;
  });
```

Then in the controller:

```
  myAppModule.controller('studentsController', ['$scope', 'studentFactory', function ($scope, studentFactory){
      $scope.students = [];
      /*
      studentFactory.getStudents(function (data){
          $scope.students = data;
      });*/
      $scope.students = studentFactory.getStudents();

      /*
      $scope.removeStudent = function(index) {
          console.log(index);
          studentFactory.removeStudent(function (index, data){
              console.log(data);
          });
      };*/
      $scope.students = studentFactory.removeStudent(index);
  }])
```

Return statements make the code so much simpler.

Comment: I was going to recommend this but presumably, the factory is going to do some async work like a web service which can then pass data back through this callback.  If that's the case, it should use a Promise/Observable but that's a different topic.